# EF Core 2: The MERGE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: c#, t-sql, entity-framework-core, .net-core-2.0

I have following classes:

```
public class GSProject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<GSPoint> Points { get; set; }
    public ICollection<GSPlanarSurface> PlanarSurfaces { get; set; }
}

public class GSPoint
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? PlanarSurfaceId { get; set; }
    public GSPlanarSurface PlanarSurface { get; set; }
}

public class GSPlanarSurface
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public ICollection<GSPoint> Points { get; set; }

        public int? PxyId { get; set; }
        public GSPoint Pxy { get; set; }

        public int? PyId { get; set; }
        public GSPoint Py { get; set; }
}
```

and context class (OnModelCreating() related content):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<GSPlanarSurface>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Points)
                .WithOne(e => e.PlanarSurface)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.PlanarSurfaceId);
```

Then I created ef migration and related migration .cs file content is:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "GSPoints",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    PlanarSurfaceId = table.Column<int>(nullable: true),
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_GSPoints", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_GSPoints_GSPlanarSurfaces_PlanarSurfaceId",
                        column: x => x.PlanarSurfaceId,
                        principalTable: "GSPlanarSurfaces",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
                });
```

Error:
{System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The MERGE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_GSPoints_GSPlanarSurfaces_PlanarSurfaceId". The conflict occurred in database "GSTDb", table "dbo.GSPlanarSurfaces", column 'Id'.


appears if I try to call:

```
context.Set<GSProject>().Add(entity);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

entity is an instance of GSProject with a few GSPoints and without any instance of GSPlanarSurface (entity.PlanarSurfaces Count = 0)

**EDIT:**
and here is a script auto generated in t-sql for the key:

```
USE [GSTDb]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[GSPoints]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_GSPoints_GSPlanarSurfaces_PlanarSurfaceId] FOREIGN KEY([PlanarSurfaceId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[GSPlanarSurfaces] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[GSPoints] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_GSPoints_GSPlanarSurfaces_PlanarSurfaceId]
GO
```

I executed simple tsql script:

```
insert into GSProjects ([Description] ,[Name]) values ('d1', 'proj1')
insert into GSPoints([Number], [IsSlave] ,[X], [Y], [Z]) values (0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
insert into GSPoints([GSProjectId], [Number], [IsSlave] ,[X], [Y], [Z]) values (5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

and there were no problems with insertion. First GSPoint has GSProjectId set to null, second GSPoint has GSProjectId set to non null value (5 here). Both ones have GSPlanarSurfaceId set to null and both were inserted correctly.

Comment: why do you have reference to GSPoint from GSProject? GSPlanarSurface already owns Points

Comment: there are GSPoints which are not related to any GSPlanarSurface. Also I would like to have a direct access from GSProject to all GSPoints

Comment: That kind of relationship is a little bit fishy. You would want to simplify those relations.

Comment: @Progressive what do you mean exactly? There is a relationship between GSProject-GSPoint as 1 to 0 or more. Also there may be GSPlanarSurfaces which 'contains' 0 or more GSPoints. Two of those GSPoints are specific (Pxy, Py). I can remove Pxy/Py relations from GSPlanarSurface and add flags inside GSPoint (i.e GSPoint { public bool isPxy; public bool isPy; } but I think it is not a good idea. Maybe you could post an answer with idea how to simplify it and it may be a solution

Comment: @ael I've already read your code. I personally would try to avoid such hidden circular relations due to complexity. But I won't provide an answer for it. Because it is not this question's interest. The answers below should provide a solution to your main problem. Have a nice day =)

Comment: what's the content of `entity` which you add to the context? Also, your t-sql for inserting on `GSPoint` doesn't match your class definition (where do `Number`, `IsSlave`, `X`, `Y` and `Z` field come from?). Also you say `GSPoint` has a `GSProjectId` which is not shown (neither on the model nor in the t-sql). Make sure you have not removed something that might be of interest when trimming (such as the rest of the model definition or the actual contents of what you are inserting)

Comment: @Jcl, yes you have a right, my tsql doesn't match for class definition, because for simplifying I omit other properties. IMO all those other properties are not important here (I know that I could do a wrong assumption, but still I belive that other primitive properties doesn't matter here).  And regarding to GSProjectId - there is GSProjectId in last tsql insertion.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is not related to EntityFramework. In my case PlanarSurfaceId was set by default to 0. I changed it to null and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, I implemented "import" function to sql from excel table, where all data was "common names" and when finding references for correct ID to particular column via firstordefault() I got 0 as result - not found, so in attemts to save context, I got this error. I got same error even when I tried to delete whole table data, while another table keeps ID used by master table. I hope this helps for some1, i spent a lot of time debugging this, because test import of 10 rows was good, and full (36k rows) throws me this error over and over.